# Customizing DevExpress DataGrid pagination

Tags: angular, datagrid, devexpress

Can we change the page scrolling so there’s a way to show the next 5 pages?  So for example in the screenshot attached I was immediately able to move to page 5, but if I then want to go to a later page I have to click one at a time. So to get from where I am now to page 25 I have to click each page in between.  It would be good if after page 5  I can scroll to see pages 6-10, then again to see 11-15 etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact displayMode is the best built-in solution that'll be available in v21.2. You can check the following demo to see how it will look like in the next version: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ArtemDevExpress/pen/mdWRGwM?editors=1010).

`

```
$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        showBorders: true,
        paging: {
            pageSize: 5
        },
        pager: {
            displayMode: 'compact',
            showInfo: true
        },
        columns: []
    });
```

`